# Getting the part of the current URL in Laravel 7/8

Tags: php, laravel, url, laravel-blade

How to get the current URL without the first part dynamically?

For example:

`www.google.com/en/second` => `/second`

`www.google.com/en/second/third` => `/second/third`

Where to put the function or how to implement this in the current blade view?

Comment: Take a look at this package: https://github.com/spatie/url

Comment: @hmrneves That's more or less the same functionality, Symfony/Laravel offers, isn't it?

Comment: @shaedrich, yes, basically

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Request::segments`:

```
implode('/', array_slice(request()->segments(), 1));
```

Answer (score -1):

All http link:

```
$link = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]"; // www.google.com/en/second/third
```

Just requested link:

```
$requested_link = "$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";  // en/second/third
```

If you do not want any part of link, replace it with `""`:

```
str_replace("en/", "", $requested_link); // second/third
```

You can put this code anywhere in view or controller. For example in view:

```
<?php
function get_url(){
   $requested_link = "$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
   return str_replace("en/", "", $requested_link);
}
?>
```

Answer (score -2):

Get the current URL including the query string...

```
echo url()->full();
```